# How to pass if python dict get method don't match

Tags: python

I'm refactoring the code and the actual structure is the following:

```
if 'brand_id' in associate_bike:
    self.brand_id = associate_bike['brand_id']
if 'category_id' in associate_bike:
    self.category_id = associate_bike['category_id']
```

I want to use the `.get` method like this =>

```
self.brand_id = associate_bike.get('brand_id', do_nothing)
```

That part of do_nothing, how I can implement? because if I put something there the value will be assigned right?

Comment: Does `self.brand_id` already have an assigned value before this line of code?  If so, then `self.brand_id` is what you want in place of `do_nothing`.  If not, there's nothing you can do, as an assignment statement has to assign *something*.

Comment: If you use `.get()`, even with `None` as the default parameter, the behavior of your code will be fundamentally different if the `self` object does not already have the attributes `brand_id` and `category_id`.

Comment: yes, is None! Tyy man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the attribute already exists, use its original value:

```
self.brand_id = associate_bike.get('brand_id', self.brand_id)
```